# RxJS subscription not firing

Tags: angular, rxjs

Currently learning RxJS. I have an integer `selectedCourseIndex` within a service that I'd like a separate component to subscribe to.

**courses-section.service.ts**

```
private selectedCourseIndex: number = -1; //this number can change from another method
private selectedCourseIndexUpdated = new Subject<number>();

getSelectedCourseUpdateListener(){
    return this.selectedCourseIndexUpdated.asObservable();
}
```

**courses-section.component.ts**

```
  private selectedCourseIndex: number = -1; //Placeholder initial selectedCourseIndex until new one given on init from courses-section service
  private selectedCourseSub: Subscription;

  constructor( public coursesSectionService: CoursesSectionService ){}

  ngOnInit(){
   this.selectedCourseIndex = 
   this.coursesSectionService.getSelectedCourseIndex();
   this.selectedCourseSub = this.coursesSectionService
    .getSelectedCourseUpdateListener()
    .subscribe((selectedCourseIndex: number) => {
      this.selectedCourseIndex = selectedCourseIndex;
      console.log('this fires when subscription updates'); //this never fires once
    });
  }
```

However, the subscription never fires, either when it initally subscribes or when the integer changes. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 4):

"Subject" observable does not replay the previous values on subscribe. Your subscription will only fire if you do the following in your service [somehow] -

```
this.selectedCourseIndexUpdated.next(<your new number>);
```

To fire subscription on each subscribe [to get the last emitted value] you should use "BehaviorSubject" instead of Subject like -

```
private selectedCourseIndexUpdated = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
```

BehaviorSubject replay the last emitted value on each subscription. Notice BehaviorSubject constructor takes the default value.

Comment: I thought the point of subject observables were to emit their current value to anyone subscribed?

Comment: "subsrcibe" to "Subject" will receive all the values which are emitted after the subscription. While BehaviorSubject always emits the last value on each new subscription. Refer - https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject#subject and https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject#behaviorsubject

Comment: Sure, but my subject subscription isn't even receiving the new values after its subscribed. When selectedCourseIndex changes, there is no console.log

Comment: You mean from this line - this.selectedCourseIndex = selectedCourseIndex;? If yes, then assigning new value is not sufficient. you need to perform "this.selectedCourseIndexUpdated.next(<your new number>)". You can do the following - Have a method in your service named "updateIndex(newIndex) { this.selectedCourseIndex = newIndex; this.selectedCourseIndexUpdated.next(newIndex);}". Call this function from where you want to update the index. Beaware that this will cause recursion if you call from subscribe().

Comment: But why doesn't anything in my current subscription fire when selectedCourseIndex changes?

Comment: Please check if you are changing the value AFTER subscribe() is called on your subject. Anything changed BEFORE subscribe will not fire the subscription.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194517/discussion-between-user2216584-and-ethernetz).

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if i am wrong,

Your problem: you want the current (or latest) value that an observable has irrespective of whether someone has emitted a value right now or not.

Answer: 
A **Subject** or **Observable** doesn’t have a current value. When a value is emitted, it is passed to subscribers and the observable is done with it. Observable will only come to action when another value is emitted to the subject stream.

If you want to have a current value, use **BehaviorSubject** which is designed for exactly the purpose you need, it keeps the last emitted value, irrespective of when it was emitted and immediately conveys that to new subscribers.

Note: It also has a method **getValue()** to get the current value.

---

another problem you are facing.

Problem: your current code doesn’t seems to work.

Answer:
Let me give an example as how i work with **Observable** -

**Courses-action.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from ‘@angular/core’;
import { Subject } from ‘rxjs’;

@Injectable()
Export class CoursesActionService {
  Public selectedCourseIndexUpdated = new Subject<any>();
  Public isCourseIndexUpdated$ = this.selectedCourseIndexUpdated.asObservable();

Public announceSelectedCourseIndex(response: any) {
  this.selectedCourseIndexUpdated.next(response);
}
```

Some random file who emits a value to the subscriber -

```
this.coursesActionService.announceSelectedCourseIndex(453);
```

Some random file who listens to the emitted value -

```
this.coursesActionService.isCourseIndexUpdated$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
.subscribe(res => console.log(‘i have the response’, res));
```

Comment: Why do we have to cast Subject as Observable? Why can't we subscribe directly to observable?

Comment: @ColbyBoren your question will require me to explain the working of observables and what role does subject plays in them. What is multicasting and unicasting. For that, let me direct you to an appropriate resource - https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-subjects-339428a1815b I think this link will be enough to give you a basic understanding of subject and their role in observables.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody has been searching around for this with no solutions, make sure that there are no JS errors prior to the subscription being made. I had that and was going nuts trying to figure out what was going on only for the line right before the subscription was erroring out.