# Unable to subscribe the Subject data

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I am using a shared service to emit data using Subject. In a component I am trying to subscribe the Subject data, but It never subscribes

I am sending index data via Subject in component A as shown below 
component A

```
export class ComponentA {
  onEditTestCase(index: number){
    this.sharedService.startedEditing.next(index);
  }
}
```

I am using a shared service to emit index data using Subject.
shared.service.ts

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

export class SharedService {

constructor(private sharedService: SharedService, private router: Router) {}

  startedEditing = new Subject<number>();
}
```

In component B, I am trying to subscribe, but it never subscribes.
component B

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
export class ComponentB {
subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private router: Router, private sharedService: SharedService, 
  private route: ActivatedRoute) {}


ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.sharedService.startedEditing
    .subscribe((index: number) => {
      this.editIndex = index;
      this.editMode = true;
      this.editedTestCase = this.sharedService.getTestCase(this.editIndex);
      this.testForm.setValue({
        testid: this.editedTestCase.testid,
        testPriority: this.editedTestCase.testPriority,
        testSummary: this.editedTestCase.testSummary
      });
    });
   }
 }
```

Am I doing anything wrong in the above code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469412/rxjs-subscription-not-firing/56469442?noredirect=1#comment99530382_56469442

Comment: Are you using the same sharedService instance in both components?

Comment: Is the service a singleton?

Comment: How are you creating the service instance in component A and component B? The service you show us has no @Injectable annotation and you did not show us the constructors of the components.

Comment: I have added the constructor code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `ReplaySubject` instead of using `Subject`.

try to implemet below code

common.setvice.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ReplaySubject} from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CommonService {

  private startedEditing = new ReplaySubject<any>();
  public startedEditing$ = this.startedEditing.asObservable();
  constructor() { }

  setData(data) {
    this.startedEditing.next(data);
  }

}
```

a.compomnent.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonService } from './common.service'

@Component({ templateUrl: 'a.component.html' })
export class AComponent {
    constructor( 
        private commonService: CommonService
     ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.commonService.setData('data from component A');
    }
}
```

b.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonService } from './common.service'

@Component({ templateUrl: 'b.component.html' })
export class BComponent {
    constructor( 
        private commonService: CommonService
     ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.commonService.startedEditing$.subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data); // this will print "data from component A";
        });
    }
}
```

Let me know if above code not clear.

Comment: I didn't understand the Common service code. Is 'data' same as 'startedEditing' in my code? @raghul selvam

Comment: yes!, i updated the code with "startedEditing" variable

Comment: I used the same code as you mentioned. without emitting the data I tried to load the component and its getting subscribed. When I emit some data, it must subscribe right?

Comment: this is because BehaviorSubject needs initial value to initiate, that why we pass "null" while declaring, i have updated the code with "ReplaySubject", this does not require initiative, now check and let me know

refer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qccvdp

Comment: I used the ReplaySubject, setData method is called in CommonService, but again in component B its not getting Subscribed. Using Behavior Subject it was subscribed, but it has an initial value. Not sure what's wrong now

Comment: Can  you check the slackblitz example and let me know, everything works for me

Comment: Its working now. I was not navigating to the component, now its getting subscribed

Answer (score 0):

Change your Subject to be a private property, and return the Subject as an Observable using a property getter.
Also make sure you are using the same instance of the service, define it as a provider at module level or a one level up inside a parent component.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
export class SharedService {
private startedEditing = new Subject<number>();

public get StartEditing(): Observable<number> {
return this.startedEditing.asObservable();
}
```

Comment: What is difference between returning a Subject or asObservable?

Comment: There is no logical difference. It's just cleaner because you prevent components from calling next()