# Subscribe to a service of a local library

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx-store

I have created an Angular library, which gets build with ngpackagr when I build my main application. Everything works fine, however I now have following use-case:

In my library I have a service, which does something. I need to wait for it to finish, so what I though about was doing this in my LibraryService:

**LibraryService**

```
reload = new Subject<any>();

// Do something else and after some time:

this.reload.next()
```

and in my real application code, I have another service which should just listen to it:

```
this.libraryService.reload.subscribe(()=>{})
```

But the subscribe will never get called. The reload subject and my service don't seem to know about each other.

What do I need to do? I already imported the library module in my app.module.ts

Comment: try changing your `Subject` to `BehaviorSubject`. `BehaviorSubject` emits the last value to all the subscribers. While `Subject` emits the value only if there is a subscriber on performing `subject.next()`. It does not emit the previous value. Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469412/rxjs-subscription-not-firing/56469442#56469442

Comment: You should not expose a `Subject` in your service, you should keep it private and expose a linked `Observable`

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with in which life cycle hook you place the subscription
if you run this in sequence you will notice the subscribe will ever get called

```
reload = new Subject<any>();
this.reload.next()
this.reload.subscribe(()=>{})
```

subscriptions has to be made before `next()`

consider put the subscribe in constructor see if it works and call next() when content are rendered or in `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: Ok I have now narrowed it down to the constructor being called two times. I have included the Library Module in my App module. This calls the JS file of the compiled service. However in my service where I add it as a dependency it gets called again but this time the Typescript file of the services gets called (in the debugger)